# How to include a Python instance in a deployable Electron app?

Tags: python, electron

I'm not sure I understand this correctly: The Electron apps that are created with electron forge, for example, do not contain full python environments out of the box.
Hence, to run an Electron-Python app, Python must already be present on the user's device.
In most situations this is certainly the case. But what if it is not? How can I integrate a 'standalone' Python instance into my Electron app?

The question here is not whether this is a stupid / smart idea. I'm rather looking for an answer about how and whether it is possible. Apart from that, judging comments are of course accepted ;)